# Why can't i get the contents of a input type=text?

Tags: javascript, html, text, input, textbox

I have a text box where the user can type something. For some reason i can't get the contents of that textbox, all i get is "undefined".

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

***HTML***

```
<div id="Text">
    <input type="text" id="TextBox">
</div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
function addText() {
    var TextBoxContent = document.getElementsByName("TextBox").value;
    alert(TextBoxContent);
}
```

Comment: when is `addText` called?

Comment: I don't see your input having a name? Make it <input type="text" id="TextBox" name="TextBox">... Maybe that will work? Or use getElementById instead

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns an array IIRC

Comment: Your `input` field doesn't have the `name` `TextBox`. And it would return a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want `getElementByID` not `getElementsByName`.

Comment: Thanks, been fiddling with the code so much that i must have forgotten to change that back :D

Answer (score 0):

You got confused with Name and ID. 
 HTML :

```
<div id="Text">
<input type="text" id="TextBox"> </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function addText() {
    var TextBoxContent = document.getElementsById("TextBox").value;
    alert(TextBoxContent);
  }
```